# how to fade in and fade out added controls in video like default controls

Tags: javascript, video

I added some controls like rewind or reload to the video on my page but I want these added controls to fade in/out like default controls of video by moving the mouse(fade in) and stop moving after 2sec(fade out).

```js
 var videoMov = document.getElementById("video1");
    videoMov.onmousemove = function () {
        if (videoMov.currentTime > 0 && !videoMov.paused && !videoMov.ended && videoMov.readyState > 2) {
            let timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                $(".reload-video").fadeOut("slow");
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <video id="video1" muted class="col-12 video-tut" height="720" controls controlsList="  " poster="./images/6.jpg">
                            <source src="./video/1.mkv#t=15,120">

                        </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after test a few ways I found the answer.

```js
let sit = 0;
    let timeout;
    var videoMov = document.getElementById("video1");
    videoMov.onmousemove = function () {
        if (videoMov.currentTime > 0 && !videoMov.paused && !videoMov.ended && videoMov.readyState > 2) {
            if (sit === 1) {
                $(".reload-video").css("display", "inline");
                $(".rewind-video").css("display", "inline");
            }
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
              if(!videoMov.paused){
                $(".reload-video").fadeOut();
                $(".rewind-video").fadeOut();
                sit = 1; 
              }else{
                $(".reload-video").css("display", "inline");
                $(".rewind-video").css("display", "inline");
              }     
            }, 2500);
        }
    }
```